# Let $Tx(t) = (1+t^2)x(1-t^2)$. Is $T$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $Tx(t) = (1+t^2)x(1-t^2)$. Is $T$ a homeomorphism for

- $T: C[-1,1] \to  C[-1,1]$,
- $T: C[0,1] \to  C[-1,1]$,
- $T: C[0,1] \to  C[0,1]$?

To show $T$ is a homeomorphism I need to show it is bijective and continous.
Since in general $C$ is a set of continuous functions can I claim that $T$ is also continuous. I am not sure how to show bijection.

Comment: What have you tried? You must show that each $T$ is (or is not) both one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $Tx(1)=Tx(-1)$ for all $x$. This discards the first two candidates, since neither can be surjective.

So we are left with the last one. If we write $g(t)=1-t^2$, then $g\in C[0,1]$ and it has an inverse $g^{-1}(t)=\sqrt{1-t}$. With $h(t)=1+t^2$, we have 
$$
Tx=h\,x\circ g.
$$
If we define
$$
Sx=\frac{x\circ g^{-1}}{2-t},
$$
then $TSx=STx=x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if defined on $[-1,1]$, the map $Tx$ is always even, so in particular $T$ cannot be surjective if the codomain is $C[-1,1]$. That leaves one case to check. For this case, think separately about the maps $T_1x(t)=x(1-t^2)$ and $T_2x(t)=(1+t^2)x(t)$.